# SSIS Importing Excel Data

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I've been tasked with importing data from an excel spreadsheet in to a table in SQL 2012. The spreadsheet will have data added to it monthly.

My plan, is to use SSIS to create a workflow to do this, I then will use SQL Job agent to execute the workflow at the beginning of every month to add in the new data.

One problem i can think of with this plan is the spreadsheet is going to become huge and eventually exceed the excel maximum rows. Instead of adding to the one spreadsheet I could have a new spreadsheet for each month? Though I'm not sure how I can use the workflow to pick the newest spreadsheet to add to the table

I'm a complete novice to SSIS, there might even be a more practical way of doing this whole process, so please feel free to offer suggestions.

Comment: Can you save the spreadsheet as a csv (flat file)?

Comment: Very good suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why inserting data into one Excel worksheet??

Inserting data into one Excel worksheet or even one workbook (Excel file) is not a good practice at all, you have to think in another way, you can create a new Excel file each time new data comes and save historical data in another repository or directory (if you need to). Or as @TabAlleman suggested if you can use flat files, it is more recommended since reading data from Excel is more difficult. But also make sure that you will not store all data in one flat file.

Comment: Thanks @Hadi I will take that info on board